# jQuery functions not resolving

Tags: jquery, javascript-framework, javascript

I'm new to both stack overflow and using jQuery from scratch, so forgive me for any incorrect formatting (or just omitting code altogether) and for obviously shoddy coding practice.

I'm compiling a portfolio here:
`Question answered, link removed`

If you try to click on the links in the navigation, there's a fadeOut>fadeIn effect resolving. Between Portal and About, the links work gorgeously, but if you click on Journal, Resources, or Contact, the text breaks and fails to fadeOut when navigating away from them.

I could replace the innerHTML of a single div, but I'd prefer to use this formatting for swapping the content. Can anyone tell me why it works with the first two links but breaks for the other three when I coded them identically?

Comment: [SSCCE](http://robzu.com/sscce-short-self-contained-correct-compilable-example/) - Please provide the applicable code directly, and provide a link if desired.

Comment: You might want to put the code here, there's no science to it - actually, you had to or this will be as good as closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this will fix your issue, but I noticed all your conditional checks are using a single equals sign instead of double (or even better, triple!) equals.

Try changing all of your conditions from this:

```
else if (about=true)
```

to this:

```
else if (about===true)
```

Edit: after looking over the javascript a little longer, i noticed you have A LOT of unnecessary redundant code. i've written a small demo on jsfiddle that will hopefully help you trim your code down a lot.

http://jsfiddle.net/FdeM9/

```
$('a').on('click', function () {
    var clickedDiv = this;
    var visibleDiv = $('div:visible');
    var divToShow = $('div').eq(parseInt(clickedDiv.innerHTML)-1);

    if (visibleDiv[0] === divToShow[0]) {
        return;
    }

    visibleDiv.fadeOut(500, function () {
        divToShow.fadeIn(500);
    });
});​
```

Comment: Actually, it fixed most of it, indeed. However, Journal can't seem to navigate to Resources or Contact and Resources still breaks. o_O

Comment: @Kwon your link seems to be working perfectly now (in chrome, atleast) edit - there's still something wrong with journal.

Comment: Works beautifully. Once I made sense of it, I implemented it and it works great. Thanks so much. :)

Answer (score 2):

You're supposed to use double-equals `==` for comparisons in your if-statements.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure how I missed that. I did make the changes, however, and found that I still have some trouble navigating between a few of the links.

Comment: For starters, I think the code in the `$('#nav_05')` block is supposed to check if `journal==true` instead of `resources==true`.  In fact, a lot of those checks seem to be incorrect on the #nav_04, #nav_05.

Comment: Ah, the plague of redundant coding. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the assignment operator(=) with the comparison operator(== or === for the typed comparison).

Since your conditions are reading from boolean variables, you can just do something like:

if(condition) {

}

Also your script tags are missing the type attributes.

Also you should encase those event binding calls inside a function and attach that function to the onReady(jQuery(document).ready) event.

Also in global variables are evil(or at least should be avoided). Looking at your code, it seems like you are planning to use those global flags to enable or disable certain menu items? Why not just control the rendering of those menu items in the first place that way you won't need the global variables.

Comment: I fixed the comparison operators (and added the type attributes instead of being lazy), but would attaching the script to an onReady event really necessary or is it just good coding practice? You're spot on with your last point though. Are you suggesting the use of ajax or am I missing something obvious and simpler?

Comment: You are probably using some php code to control the values of the boolean flags at the top. My suggestion is instead of doing that, use the same server side php conditions to control whether the individual menu items are rendered/written. Since you mentioned ajax, are you trying to enable/disable some menu items without reloading the page? then in that case, you can instead use style classes to control that.

Comment: the ready is necessary since you might end up moving those scripts into a separate file or move the script tag before the actual menu divs. The reason why you want to execute your initialization on the onReady event is that your initialization code are relying on the readiness of the DOM.

Comment: I'm considering scrapping the need for individual menu items and programming a more universal function to save the need for so much code (that I can call whenever I need the event to resolve). I've never taken the time to make heads or tails of Ajax from the ground up, so I'm not going to start quite yet.  

I will actually take your advice there.  

Thank you so much :).

Answer (score 0):

the easiest and cleanest way is to give all the menu items a class of lets say "menu"

then use this

```
$(".menu").click(function () {
    $(".menu").fadeOut().delay(500);
    $(this).fadeIn();
}
```

Comment: That makes sense in my head so I'll give that a shot, thank you.